# remove default row selection datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that when it loaded first row is selected. I want to delete a record but I don't want first row select. I want message to user that first select a row then click delete button. I try these code but they don't worked.

```
//kharidDataGridView.Rows[0].Selected = false;

//kharidDataGridView.ClearSelection();

//kharidDataGridView.CurrentCell = null;
```

I use below codes in WPF:

```
object item = datagrideview1.SelectedItem;
            if (item == null)
            {
                //message to user
            }
```

thank you

Comment: Execute ClearSelection after databind

Comment: Call ClearSelection() and CurrentCell = null after DataBind

Answer (score 1):

You can remove default selected row by handling data-grid loaded event

```
private void datagrideview1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      datagrideview1.SelectedIndex = -1;
 }
```